# Using nested CASE statements in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, nested, case

My logic just must be a little funky because when I test to make sure that these `CASE` statements are true, I will not get the expected resulted...

for example, if `Sample1 = 'FI'`, `Sample2 = 'GOVT'` and `Sample3 = 'GOVT'`, I do not get `'OKFI'` ... I know I must be having some quirky logic somewhere...

Any ideas on best practices with these things?

```
CREATE FUNCTION SampleFunction
(
    @Sample1 varchar(50),
  @Sample2 varchar(50) = null,
  @Sample3 varchar(50) = null
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN

declare @output varchar(255)



SET @output = 

CASE WHEN @Sample1 = 'CASH' THEN 'CASH' 

WHEN @Sample1 = 'ST' THEN 
    CASE WHEN @Sample2 ='TBILL' THEN
        CASE WHEN @Sample3 = 'TBILL' THEN 'OKFI' 

WHEN @Sample1 = 'FI' THEN
    CASE WHEN @Sample2 = 'GOVT' THEN
        CASE WHEN @Sample3 = 'GOVT' THEN 'OKFI'

WHEN @Sample1 = 'DERV' THEN
    CASE WHEN @Sample2 = 'CURRCONT' THEN 
        CASE WHEN @Sample3 = 'FORWARD' THEN 'CASH'
            WHEN @Sample3 = 'SPOT' THEN 'CASH' 
WHEN @Sample2 = 'SWAP' THEN
    CASE WHEN @Sample3 = 'CURRSWAP' THEN 'CASH'
        WHEN @Sample3 = 'INDXSWAP' THEN 'OTHER'

WHEN @Sample2 = 'FUTURE' THEN
CASE WHEN @Sample3 = 'COMFUT' THEN 'COM'
    WHEN @Sample3 = 'BFUT' THEN 'OKFI'
    WHEN @Sample3 = 'NDXFUT' THEN 'OKSHARES' 
    WHEN @Sample3 = 'EQFUT' THEN 'OKSHARES' 
    WHEN @Sample3 = 'CURRFUT' THEN 'CASH'

WHEN @Sample2 = 'OPTION' THEN
CASE WHEN @Sample3 = 'CUROPTION' THEN 'CASH' END

ELSE 'OTHER' 

END END END
END END END
END END END RETURN @Output

END -- FUNCTION
```

Comment: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SampleFunction, Line 49
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.`

Comment: Oops. Let me edit the procedure to show the proper amount of ENDs. Sorry about that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create @table variable or even a physical permanent table with columns `Sample1, Sample2, Sample3, Output` - insert all your combinations and desired outputs in it and then just select `Output` from it based on your `@Sample1`, `@Sample2`,`@Sample3` variables.

This way with dozens of CASEs inside CASEs you are just going to get lost.

Something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SampleFunction2
    (
      @Sample1 VARCHAR(50) ,
      @Sample2 VARCHAR(50) = NULL ,
      @Sample3 VARCHAR(50) = NULL
    )
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS 
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @output VARCHAR(255)


        DECLARE @tempResults TABLE
            (
              Sample1 VARCHAR(50) ,
              Sample2 VARCHAR(50) ,
              Sample3 VARCHAR(50) ,
              [Output] VARCHAR(255)
            )

        INSERT  INTO @tempResults
        VALUES   ( 'CASH', NULL, NULL, 'CASH' )         
                ,( 'ST', 'TBILL', 'TBILL', 'OKFI' )
                ,( 'FI', 'GOVT', 'GOVT', 'OKFI' )
                ,( 'DERV', 'CURRCONT', 'FORWARD', 'CASH' )
                ,( 'DERV', 'CURRCONT', 'SPOT', 'CASH' )
                ,( NULL, 'SWAP', 'CURRSWAP', 'CASH' )
                ,( NULL, 'SWAP', 'INDXSWAP', 'OTHER' )
                ,( NULL, 'FUTURE', 'COMFUT', 'COM' )
                ,( NULL, 'FUTURE', 'BFUT', 'OKFI' )
                ,( NULL, 'FUTURE', 'NDXFUT', 'OKSHARES' )
                ,( NULL, 'FUTURE', 'EQFUT', 'OKSHARES' )
                ,( NULL, 'FUTURE', 'CURRFUT', 'CASH' )
                ,( NULL, 'OPTION', 'CUROPTION', 'CASH' )


        SELECT  @output = [Output]
        FROM    @tempResults
        WHERE   (@Sample1 IS NULL OR Sample1 = @Sample1)
            AND (@Sample2 IS NULL OR Sample2 = @Sample2)
            AND (@Sample3 IS NULL OR Sample3 = @Sample3)

        IF @output IS NULL SET @output = 'OTHER' 

        RETURN @output
    END
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03bfc/2)**

And if you want to stick with CASEs, the problem with your original query is misplacing the `END`s :

```
CREATE FUNCTION SampleFunction
(
    @Sample1 varchar(50),
  @Sample2 varchar(50) = null,
  @Sample3 varchar(50) = null
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN

declare @output varchar(255)



SET @output = 

CASE WHEN @Sample1 = 'CASH' THEN 'CASH' 

    WHEN @Sample1 = 'ST' THEN 
        CASE WHEN @Sample2 ='TBILL' THEN
            CASE WHEN @Sample3 = 'TBILL' THEN 'OKFI' 
            END
        END      

    WHEN @Sample1 = 'FI' THEN
        CASE WHEN @Sample2 = 'GOVT' THEN
            CASE WHEN @Sample3 = 'GOVT' THEN 'OKFI'
            END
        END

    WHEN @Sample1 = 'DERV' THEN
        CASE WHEN @Sample2 = 'CURRCONT' THEN 
            CASE WHEN @Sample3 = 'FORWARD' THEN 'CASH'
                WHEN @Sample3 = 'SPOT' THEN 'CASH' 
            END
        END      

    WHEN @Sample2 = 'SWAP' THEN
        CASE WHEN @Sample3 = 'CURRSWAP' THEN 'CASH'
            WHEN @Sample3 = 'INDXSWAP' THEN 'OTHER'
        END

    WHEN @Sample2 = 'FUTURE' THEN
        CASE WHEN @Sample3 = 'COMFUT' THEN 'COM'
            WHEN @Sample3 = 'BFUT' THEN 'OKFI'
            WHEN @Sample3 = 'NDXFUT' THEN 'OKSHARES' 
            WHEN @Sample3 = 'EQFUT' THEN 'OKSHARES' 
            WHEN @Sample3 = 'CURRFUT' THEN 'CASH'
        END

    WHEN @Sample2 = 'OPTION' THEN
        CASE WHEN @Sample3 = 'CUROPTION' THEN 'CASH' 
        END

    ELSE 'OTHER' 


  END RETURN @Output

END -- FUNCTION
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ba5e/2)**

Comment: I opted for the CASE statements, only because it's a function and most likely will never be changed... I see how it can be confusing and appreaciate the alterante solution. I will use that on my next approach. Thanks very much!